# MYSQL replace id with name from another table

Tags: mysql

I've been having a lot of trouble with a Join statement that I can't get to work.  I'm relatively new to MySQL so would appreciate some help.

I have 2 tables under the database "CoreProtect", co_command and co_user.  co_command has 2 columns, message and user.  co_user has another 2 columns, "rowid" and "user".  rowid refers to the "user" column in co_command, where the "user" from co_command is the same as the "row_id" in co_user, the user field in co_user stores the actual string name of the user. (I hope that makes sense)

The query I am using is:

```
SELECT user
COUNT(message)
FROM co_command
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(message)
ORDER BY count(message)
```

This does what I expect, however it gives the numerical value that refers to the other table of the names.  I'd like the output to give the Name of the User and the count, instead of the numerical refrence to the other table.

I know I need a JOIN statement for this and I've researched it but have been unable to make it work.

I can find the string username from the other table with

```
SELECT user
FROM co_user
WHERE rowid="User Value from co_command";
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you need  a join

```
SELECT c.user, u.user 
    , COUNT(message)
FROM co_command c
INNER JOIN co_user u ON. u.rowid = c.user
GROUP BY c.user, u.user 
ORDER BY count(message)
```